# Generate csv and pdf reports in Arabic Language with HttpServletResponse (java8 and eclipse)

Tags: java, csv, pdf, arabic

I am trying to generate CSV and pdf reports containing caracters in Arabic language.  After exporting the files, the arabic caracters are displaying like "­Ø­Ø­Ø­Ù‡Ù‡Ù‡Ù" instead of Arabic. Please any help to solve this problem.
I’m using the code below :

```
byte[] csv = str.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getResponse();
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("application/csv; charset=UTF-8");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + exportFileName + ".csv");
        response.setContentLength(csv.length);
        response.getOutputStream().write(csv);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

PS : arabic caracters are diplaying right in the consol of Eclipse.

Comment: What encoding do you use for reading the file?

Comment: i'm using microsoft excel to read the file so its default encoding.

Comment: You may want to use that weird windows encoding (cp+a number) instead of UTF-8.

Comment: i tried it and it doesn't work

Comment: You have to add BOM to the begin of the file, so exael will know the enocding and it will work,. if you want general solution that work on windows arabic locale and english locale, use UTF 16 LE encoding and Tab as delimiter in addition to BOM, Read this for more information:
https://informatic-ar.com/csv-arabic-excel/